# Salesforce Edit page disable icon 'i' (help window) against dependent picklist

Tags: helptext

As per a fixed [Known Issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000Su0PAAS), I believe help icon is mandatory for dependent pick list. However while I'm working on application I am ending up by pressing additional tab for/with this help window. Is there no way I can remove it?

[image: Help Text Included]

Comment: just go to object settings and edit that field. Locate "Help text" and make it null. Save it.

Comment: @RohitMourya Why not just make that an answer? Needs a bit more detail but that's the solution.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Ok. I'll post it as a answer

Comment: I think the OP has misinterpreted the link in the question as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't remove that Help Text icon from dependent picklist. That is a standard behavior.

And let me correct you here that, Help Text icon appears irrespective of whether that field is required or not. However in my example, by pressing tab it doesn't sets the focus of Help Text icon. Don't know why it's happening in your case.

For reference refer below snapshot:

[image]